# Hashtable length limit java

Tags: java

In my project, I'm working with webservices. To play with them, I use an Hastable in java.
I m working with 1.6.x java version. I have an Hashtable  declared as

```
Hashtable<String, String> props1 = new Hashtable<String, String>();
```

I could put data in like this

```
props1.put("@aze", values);
```

The 9 first element: no problem, all work well. At the  10 one, it a crash... and i don't understand.

How could I do ?

many thx

edit: full code source

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Hashtable<String, String> props1 = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    props1.put("@matricule", values[0]);
    props1.put("@nom", values[1]);
    props1.put("@prenom", values[2]);
    props1.put("@email", values[3]);
    props1.put("@estoccasionnel", values[4]);
    props1.put("@adresse", values[5]);
    props1.put("@codepostal", values[6]);
    props1.put("@ville", values[7]);
    props1.put("@telfixe", values[8]);
    props1.put("@telmobile", values[9]);
}
```

code break at 
    props1.put("@telmobile", values[9]);

with error message

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9
at CommandLineCreationWebservice.main(CommandLineCreationWebservice.java:99)
```

Comment: We need to see how and what you add and expecially the row it crashes and what the error message is.

Comment: +1 to libik comment. There are no reasons for a Hashtable to be limited to 10 records, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: you shouldn't use hashtable at all. use Hashmap or ConcurrentHashMap if it has to be thread safe

Comment: Do what @JakubHr said

Comment: full code source added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
props1.put("@telmobile", values[9]);
```

the values array doesn't have a 10th value. That's the meaning of `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 9`  (zero-based index in java)

Comment: Actually it's 10th value and index number 9

Answer (score 2):

Java Hashtable is capable of storing a large amount of object (depending on your heap size). In any case it is way more, that 10.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your values array not in hashtable.
Probably your size of values array is not enough. It should be at least 10 in this case.